# What is the difference between a private and a commercial flight according to the US Customs and Border Protection?

Tags: us-cbp

From what I understand, whether or not a flight is classified as private or commercial in the eyes of US Customs and Border Protection (CBP) has nothing to do with the Federal Aviation Regulations (FAR) flight rules that they are operating under. For instance, I understand that I can legally be operating under [FAR Part 91](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.10&idno=14) and still be a commercial flight in the eyes of CBP. What then is the determining factor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [CBP eAPIS FAQ](https://eapis.cbp.dhs.gov/docs/help.html#a2), this definition is in [19 CFR 122.1](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=a329147dbf8d2fc6eb123e0adf6aeed8&mc=true&node=se19.1.122_11&rgn=div8):

> (d) *Commercial aircraft*. A “commercial aircraft” is any aircraft
>   transporting passengers and/or cargo for some payment or other
>   consideration, including money or services rendered.
>
> [...]
>
> (h) *Private aircraft*. A “private aircraft” is any aircraft engaged in
>   a personal or business flight to or from the U.S. which is not:
>
> (1) Carrying passengers and/or cargo for commercial purposes;
>
> (2) Leaving the U.S. carrying neither passengers nor cargo in order to
>   lade passengers and/or cargo in a foreign area for commercial
>   purposes; or
>
> (3) Returning to the U.S. carrying neither passengers nor cargo in
>   ballast after leaving with passengers and/or cargo for commercial
>   purposes;

Comment: Nice answer! This is good to know.

Comment: That's pretty much the FAA definition, is it not?

Comment: @MichaelHall Not exactly.  There are some situations where a Part 91 flight can accept money, but still be operating under Part 91 (such as training flights, ferry flights, and other exceptions in 14 CFR 119.1).  In this case, they would still be considered a commercial aircraft by CBP.

Comment: @Lnafziger - The OP in the question, Pondlife in his answer, me in my comment, and now you, are all saying the same thing:  If you are receiving compensation it is a commercial flight, regardless of the CFR part you are operating under.  Is there a misunderstanding?  Because I think we all agree...

Comment: @MichaelHall Well, I am the OP of the question, but in my comment here I was referring to your comment on this answer which says that it's pretty much the same definition as used by the FAA.  There are differences, which is why I asked the question in the first place (and I pointed out some of them in the previous comment).  There **are** situations where you can be paid, but still be flying under Part 91 (training, etc.).  Those would be considered commercial flights for CBP purposes though.

Comment: @Lnafziger - And my question is that even if you may be operating under part 91, if you are being compensated doesn't the FAA also consider that a commercial operation?  (commercial pilot certificate is a prerequisite for CFI)  I am just not quite understanding whether we even have a disagreement or misunderstanding at this point...

Comment: @MichaelHall Okay, I see what you are asking.  It is common for people to think of Part 91 as private and Part 135 as commercial, and I hear a lot of people say something along the lines of "if you are flying under Part 91, then you are a private flight according to CBP."  That was the reason behind my question, as it is clear that there are some operations that are conducted under Part 91 which are still commercial operations.  That's what I was trying to clarify with the question.

Comment: @Lnafziger - Got it.  I understand the common thinking, but I have never actually heard anyone assert that as the primary discriminator.  Generally the question of compensation is the first block on the commercial or not flow chart.  To that I have a twist:  What if you are operating under part 135, but are NOT receiving compensation?

Comment: @MichaelHall Then by the definition above, it would be considered private by CBP.  That's why it gets confusing for some people, lol.

Comment: Well, the Captain is getting paid so it is still commercial.  And I guess you could argue that as an optional FO flying for fun and currency, my compensation is free flight time!  ;)

Comment: @MichaelHall Right, hence the question.  CBP says that a commercial aircraft is one that is "transporting passengers and/or cargo for some payment or other consideration."  If it is a 135 trip, but you aren't receiving compensation, then it doesn't meet the definition.

Comment: @Lnafziger - You just swung totally the other way on me there...  The part 135 Company I fly with part time is transporting passengers for hire, and is therefore a commercial operation in every sense of the word.  The fact that I receive flight time in lieu of cash as a non-required crewmember would not affect that.

Comment: @MichaelHall I agree!  However, CBP would not.  Their definition is different than what the FAA uses (see the answer that we are commenting on).  If the ***actual flight in question*** does not have ***passengers and/or cargo on board for hire*** (and it doesn't meet any of the other requirements), then it is not a commercial flight per CBP rules/guidelines.  If there ***are*** paying customers ***on board***, then it would be a commercial flight per CBP.