# What are the customs decal and eAPIS requirements for flying to the Bahamas?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, flight-planning

I'm planning to rent an aircraft and fly to the Bahamas. I've got all the requirements including the Restricted Radio license.

However, there was another requirement which concerns paying of the Annual decal fee through CBP DTOPs and filling the form through eAPIS which kind of got me confused. Now I'm about to pay the annual user decal fee for a private aircraft but is this required if its a rental aircraft?

And could someone please briefly explain the difference between the two and how they should be used for my trip?

Comment: Have you tried calling Customs and asking? Seems to me the requirement is on you to obtain it as you are taking the plane out of the country and want to be able to come back in with minimal hassle.  Don't forget to check in with Both Immigrations and with Customs when you get to the Bahamas so you have the correct forms on hand when you leave.

Comment: Ask the company you're renting the plane from.  They may already have the decal.

Answer (score 1):

AOPA has a [useful guide to flying to/in the Caribbean](http://aopa.org/travel/international-travel/caribbean), including [the Bahamas](https://www.aopa.org/travel/international-travel/bahamas). To answer your specific questions:

- You do need a customs decal [if your aircraft is considered private by the CBP](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47/62), regardless of whether you own it or rent it (I've seen them myself on several aircraft that I've rented)
- eAPIS is a system [for reporting who is on board an aircraft](https://www.aopa.org/travel/international-travel/eapis-frequently-asked-questions) *every time* it crosses the US border, it has nothing to do with the decal